# How do I create a script that greps two inputs from the user

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I have a text file which has about 4/5 useful lines of detail followed by one line which says whether it is todo or waiting. Then I change the number for priority.

For example, if I want to see my third priority to do case, I write:

> grep -i 'todo 3' -B5 casemanager.txt

This outputs

---

case name

case num

detail

TODO: 1

---

If I want to search all waiting or waiting priority 2:

> grep -i 'waiting 2' -B5 casemanager.txt or 
>   grep -i 'waiting' -B5 casemanager.txt

*Question is:*

Is it possible to create a linux script that asks whether you are looking for 'waiting' or 'todo' case as input 1. Then for input 2: to ask whether you want all cases todo/waiting or cases waiting/todo by priority 1-10 for example.

Comment: The short answer to your question would be: *yes*. You're looking for the Bash `select` command. See e.g. https://linuxhint.com/bash_select_command/ and search the net.

Comment: This looks like it could work, cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a script to read input from the user and store the input in a variable 
After some if statement to check what the input is

Comment: Any small example?